# Average height of competitors for each weight category in Judo?

Tags: judo, competition, weight

It can be difficult to gauge whether you are in the 'right' weight category, i.e. whether you should stay around the same weight, try and lose some fat to drop a weight category, or try and gain some muscle mass to move up one.

Is there any information on the average height of competitive judoka in each weight class?

Answer (score 1):

The following study recorded average height (as well as other body measurements) for a sample of national/international level male Brazilian judoka:

> [image]
>
> This study compared the anthropometrical characteristics in judo athletes of different weight categories. The sample was composed by 104 Brazilian male judo athletes of national/international level from all seven official weight categories: extralightweight (-60 kg; n = 16), half-lightweight (-66 kg; n = 12), lightweight (-73 kg; n = 24), half-middleweight (-81 kg; n = 25), middleweight (-90 kg; n = 15), half-heavyweight (-100 kg; n = 7) and heavyweight (+100 kg; n = 5).
> ...
> The main results of the present study was that: (1) height differed across
> non subsequent weight categories, except for the difference between -60 kg and -66 kg;

- [Anthropometrical Profile of Judo Athletes: Comparative Analysis Between Weight Categories](https://www.scielo.cl/pdf/ijmorphol/v32n1/art07.pdf) (2014)

Comment: Methodologically, the significance levels are a bit low due to the low numbers of subjects per bracket. And there could be a bias due to the people who scout for national/international level in this federation. But interesting to have numbers at all. 